# Sheaf ext of locally free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $>1$ over a smooth projective variety. Then what is $\mathcal{E}xt^1(E,O_X)$? If it's a line bundle, I know that is zero.

Is this $H^1(\mathcal{H}om(E,O_X))$?

Comment: Your notation suggests you want sheaf ext, in which case it is zero. The second paragraph suggests global ext, in which case it may not be zero.

Comment: I want sheaf ext only. Thanks for letting me know that it's zero.